# What to name a race of rock people?

Tags: geology, races, names

I'm looking for a good name for my race of crystalline/rock people. Preferably a fancy/sciency sounding one, as "rockulon" & "bouldera" don't really fit the tone of the story.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I'm afraid this question is likely to be closed, as "what to name something" is very opinion-based. Hope you stick around, though!

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about how this site works. We aim to help people create internally consistent worlds, but answers need to be somewhat objectively comparable to one another. In its current form you are the only one who can judge whether you like an answer or not. Please try to [edit] your question to make it more objective. For the moment I am voting to put this on hold until your question corresponds to our guidelines.

Comment: Also you should try to wait a bit before accepting. It's up to you to decide what helped you but this question currently has 20 views after 25 minutes. That's not a lot and people using WorldBuilding live all around the globe. Give regulars some time to check your question and the answers presented. This can increase the answers quality.

Comment: "Bouldera" actually has a nice ring to it.  I think she might be the one that song "Brick House" is about.

Comment: Closed... now who'll name their race the Kosmochlor, or Celsian, or Ajoite, or Galena, or Lavendulan? They're mineral names FYI, like the bad guys from Sailor Moon (Beryl, Jadeite, Nephrite...)

Comment: Oh come on, now you guys are just being silly closing this! That is an excellent world building question. "I need to name my rock people in my world but I do not know how... can I please have some suggestions?". This is quintessential world building! Ping @michaelkjorling

Comment: @MichaelK Not sure why you pinged me specifically and not any of the other users who took part in putting this on hold. If you look at [our subject scope page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you will see that Worldbuilding SE is about *creation of elements* or *the effects of those elements*, which is pretty far from asking *what, specifically, should I name this item*. Please see the close reason description: "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise".

Comment: @Omnichromatid This question likely would have fared better if, instead of asking *what to name something*, you instead had asked *how to approach naming something*. It might still have been a poor fit for us (we'd basically have to see it to be sure), but such a question would have invited answers that deal more in the *why* and *how* rather than just *what*. Compare [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) which guides many of these matters across the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling As part of creating an element, **naming that element** seems rather obvious. :)

Comment: How about Balboans?

Comment: @MichaelK I disagree, but feel free to take that to [meta] if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Not that strongly no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Living Stone, Living Rock, Rock Man, Wise Rock

<strike>Google</strike> Translate... English to Latin

<sub>**(Thank you AlexP for the clean-up)**</sub>

- Living Stone: *Lapis Vivens*
- Living Rock:  *Petra Vivens*

Homo Sapiens roughly means "Wise man" according to my Google Translate-fu. So...

- Rock Man: *Homo Petraeus*
- Wise Rock: *Petra Sapiens*

Everyday speech would simplify this. I guess they would be something along the line "Petrams" or "Petras".

**NOTE**: Do know that when giving species their scientific names according to [Linnaean Taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnaean_taxonomy), you are allowed to just make stuff up and go nuts if you like.... [like so](http://www.curioustaxonomy.net/).

Bonus Fact: you know that pleasant smell just as a rain starts? The name for that is *[petrichor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrichor)*, petr(a) of course meaning "stone". :)

Comment: As regards "Wise Rock/Wise Man" - _Homo_ is the Latin for _man_, not for _wise_; the general translation for _sapiens_ is "that which thinks", so "Wise Rock" would be _Petram Sapiens_, rather than _Homo Petram_, which would be "Man of Rock" (subject to grammar corrections, e.g., it might be _petrus_ or _petra_ rather than _petram_).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Ah but of course, I messed up.

Comment: *Lapis vivens*, living stone ("viventem" is the accusative and you want the nominative). *Homo petraeus*, rocky man ("petra" is a noun and Latin does not make noun piles like English). *Petra sapiens*, wise rock ("petram" is the accusative). *Petra* is a loanword from Greek; in Latin it means a "rock" (usually a largish piece of rock), not "stone" in general.

Comment: @AlexP Thank you kindly! Edited and acknowledged. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you trawl through different geological classifications of rocks and make each of them sound racelike you'll probably have better luck.

- Igneous -> Ignocene
- Basalt -> Basaline
- etc.

Equally, adding "ite" as a suffix makes anything sound like a mineral:

[Meaning and etymology of the “ite” and “ine/ene” endings of mineral names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/meaning-and-etymology-of-the-ite-and-ine-ene-endings-of-mineral-names)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Oliver*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!